# Strange failure while logging CPU-Temp with Python to a .csv-File (Rasbperri-Pi)

Tags: python, csv, while-loop, raspberry-pi, temperature

i Try to set up my Raspberry pi with a fan. It should log the Temperature every 5 minutes and write it to a .csv-file with a Python Script. If the Temperature is hotter than 52 Degrees Celsius, it shoud turn on a USB-Hub, and turn it of if it is below that value. For now, i created a little website, to see my logged data. And here is my question: as you can see in the screenshot, it tells me sometimes [HOT] and sometimes [OK] for the same Values? Also it is not sepperating the Data like a want it to seperate (over/under 52 Degrees Celsius).

[Screenshot from my little website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXHE8.png) (This only displays my .csv-File)

My .py-code:

```html
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
from time import sleep, strftime, time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=datetime.today()
w = v.replace(day=v.day, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + timedelta(days=1)
delta_t=w-v

secs=delta_t.total_seconds()

cpu = CPUTemperature()

plt.ion()
x = []
y = []

def write_tempHot(temp):
        with open("/var/www/html/cpuTemp.csv", "a") as log:
                log.write("{0}{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S = [HOT] "),str(temp)))


def write_tempLow(temp):
        with open("/var/www/html/cpuTemp.csv", "a") as log:
                log.write("{0}{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S = [OK] "),str(temp)))



def clearTemp():
 filename = "/var/www/html/cpuTemp.csv"
        # opening the file with w+ mode truncates the file
 f = open(filename, "w+")
 f.close()

while True:
 temp = cpu.temperature
 if temp > 52:
  temp = cpu.temperature
  write_tempHot(temp)
  plt.pause(300)
  t = Timer(secs, clearTemp)
  t.start()
 else:
  temp = cpu.temperature
  write_tempLow(temp)
  plt.pause(300)
  t = Timer(secs, clearTemp)
  t.start()
```

(Also dont mind for the clearTemp()-function, i want to clear the .csv-file once a day)

Does anybody have n idea, why the results are that kind of strange?
Greetings & Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is

```
if temp > 52
```

when it should be

```
if temp >= 52.0
```

because otherwise your temperature Hi will only match if it is 53C or above.

I'd also use `time.sleep()` instead of `plt.pause()`.

For your logfile, you've got two functions to write to your logfile, I'd use one instead:

```py
def write_log(temp):
    fmt = """{when} = [{option}] {temp}"""
    datefmt = """%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"""
    option = "OK"
    with open("/var/www/html/cpuTemp.csv", "a") as log:
        when = datetime.now().strftime(datefmt)
        if temp >= 52.0:
            option = "HOT"
        log.write(fmt.format(when=when, option=option, temp=temp))
```

Finally, I do not understand why you want to truncate your logfile every 5 minutes.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! i will try this solution directly!
And the Truncation: i dont want to do it every 5 min., but its the only solution i found right now. But i´ll try different solutions these days :)! do you have an Idea how do clear the file easyly?

Comment: Ignoring the "why are you doing this" for truncating the logfile, how about rotating the filename instead? Sampling at 5 minute intervals gets you 288 lines for a day. You could update your code to check whether the day number has changed and then write to a new filename, perhaps with a datestamp appended. Or just not worry about it.

Comment: Hey, just to keep you updated: I deleted the clear-function and made a button to the website, that opens a shellcommand at my .php-website which deletes the file. So i can do it Manually if the free memorstorage is getting low :) i also added the fan and added a shellcommand in the pythonscript, that activates and deactivates the fan right next to the "option"-value you created. I made this with uhubctl. Thanks a lot for your support :) if anybody is interessted in the final result i can upload it on github, just text me